# Highchart reduce gap size in heatmap and data missing

Tags: heatmap, highcharts

Somehow the gap is not reduced, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I am using a Highcharts Heatmap. Please help me to reduce the gap between the intervals and the line should be closer. When we increase the data, some data is not showing on the graph and they are skipped. The data seems to be missing somewhere.

```
 Highcharts
            .stockChart(
                    'container',
                    {
                        chart : {
                            type : 'heatmap',
                            marginTop : 40,
                            height : 500,
                            width : 900,
                            panning : true,
                            followTouchMove : true,
                            pinchType : 0,
                            followPointer : true,
                            inverted : true,
                        },

                        data : {
                            csv : data,
                        },
                        navigator : {
                            top : 40,
                        },
                        rangeSelector : {
                            buttons : [ {
                                count : 1,
                                type : 'minute',
                                text : '1M'
                            }, {
                                count : 5,
                                type : 'minute',
                                text : '5M'
                            }, {
                                type : 'all',
                                text : 'All'
                            } ],
                            inputEnabled : false,
                            enabled : false,
                            selected : 0
                        },

                        title : {
                            text : 'Live random data'
                        },

                        exporting : {
                            enabled : true,
                            buttons : {
                                contextButton : {
                                    menuItems : [
                                            {
                                                textKey : 'viewData',
                                                onclick : function() {
                                                    this.viewData();
                                                    $('#pausereset')
                                                            .toggleClass(
                                                                    'optionsettable');
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                separator : true
                                            },
                                            {
                                                textKey : 'downloadPNG',
                                                onclick : function() {

                                                    var title = this.title.textStr;

                                                    this.exportChart({
                                                        type : 'image/png',
                                                        filename : title
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                textKey : 'downloadJPEG',
                                                onclick : function() {
                                                    var title = this.title.textStr;
                                                    this
                                                            .exportChart({
                                                                type : 'image/jpeg',
                                                                filename : title
                                                            });
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                textKey : 'downloadPDF',
                                                onclick : function() {
                                                    var title = this.title.textStr;
                                                    this
                                                            .exportChart({
                                                                type : 'application/pdf',
                                                                filename : title
                                                            });
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                textKey : 'downloadSVG',
                                                onclick : function() {
                                                    var title = this.title.textStr;
                                                    this
                                                            .exportChart({
                                                                type : 'image/svg+xml',
                                                                filename : title
                                                            });
                                                }
                                            } ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        yAxis : {
                            scrollbar : {
                                enabled : true,
                                showFull : true
                            },
                            title : {
                                text : null
                            },
                            labels : {
                                format : '{value}:00'
                            },
                            /* minPadding : 50,
                            maxPadding : 20, */
                            /* tickPositions : [ 0, 6, 12, 18, 24 ], */
                            tickWidth : 0.5,
                        /* min : 0,
                        max : 33 */
                        },
                        xAxis : {
                            reversed : true,
                            scrollbar : {
                                enabled : true,
                                showFull : true
                            },
                            tickPixelInterval : 0.5,
                        },
                        plotOptions : {
                            dataLabels : {
                                enabled : true
                            },
                            heatmap : {
                                allowPointSelect : true
                            },
                            series : {
                                pointPadding : 0,
                                groupPadding : 0.1,
                            }
                        },
                        colorAxis : {
                            stops : [ [ 0, '#84D984' ], [ 0.5, '#127B12' ],
                                    [ 0.9, '#005500' ] ],
                            min : -5
                        },

                        series : [ {
                            type : 'heatmap',
                            name : 'Random data',
                            borderWidth : 0,
                            showInNavigator : true,
                            turboThreshold : 0,
                            cropThreshold : 300,
                            /* colsize : 0.1 * 36e5, */
                            pointPadding : 0,
                            colsize : 0.1 * 36e5,
                            rowsize : 1,
                            tooltip : {
                                headerFormat : 'Temperature<br/>',
                                pointFormat : '{point.x: %H}:{point.x: %m} - {point.y}:00: <b>{point.value} ℃</b>'
                            },
                        } ]
                    });
```

[Here is the jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ax4bpj60/41/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increase the `series.colsize` value. In this case, you can set it equal to one hour interval, just like that:

```
series: [{
    type:'heatmap',
    borderWidth: 0,
    pointWidth: '100%',
    colsize: 36e5, // one hour
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: 'Temperature<br/>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%e %b, %Y} {point.y}:00: <b>{point.value} ℃</b>'
    }
}]
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/zpvdweab/1/

Comment: Thanks For your answer. But For me the Data for each hour should be like a thin line . Not much width like this. Is there any way to be like that !!!